# Error when trying to get a response from Web API URL via Javascript jQuery call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I've this piece of code which is supposed to get a JSON answer from a localhost site. If I browse this URL from Chrome, I get a good response, but if I try to run this code from the HTML page I get an error (via the VS debug).

Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  alert("hello");
  var request = $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3157/api/Products",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json"
  });
  request.done(function(msg) {
    alert("msg is: " + msg);
  });
  request.fail(function (jqXhr, textStatus) {
    alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
  });
});
```

**Update - added xml output**

```
<ArrayOfProduct xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/FirstWebApi.Models">
    <Product>
        <Category>Groceries</Category>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Name>Tomato Soup</Name>
        <Price>1</Price>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Category>Toys</Category>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Name>Yo-yo</Name>
        <Price>3.75</Price>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Category>Hardware</Category>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <Name>Hammer</Name>
        <Price>16.99</Price>
    </Product>
</ArrayOfProduct>
```

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: I simply get the word "error" back on the failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to ask someone at work I must have done something differently and got an error message of "No Transport".
From there I found the reason & solution [here](http://mike-ward.net/blog/post/00660/force-jquery-1-5-to-always-allow-cross-site-scripting)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `respone` from `url` is in `json` format

Comment: Tried to set the dataType to xml (which is how I see it in the browser) and also to remove it but it doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In order to specify `json` as the dataType you must return `json` from the endpoint otherwise you'll get a parse error since the `json` parser will be invoked explicitly.

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y2fTs/)**</kbd>

<kbd>**[Broken Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y2fTs/1/)**</kbd>

Notice the only difference is the endpoint (html vs json).

You could also try removing the `dataType` attribute and let jQuery figure it out automatically.

---

Since your xml is semantically correct, the issue must be in the headers you are sending back. Make sure the response's content type is 'text/xml'

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y2fTs/6/)**</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<script id='xmlData' type='text/html'>
<ArrayOfProduct xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/FirstWebApi.Models">
    <Product>
        <Category>Groceries</Category>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Name>Tomato Soup</Name>
        <Price>1</Price>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Category>Toys</Category>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Name>Yo-yo</Name>
        <Price>3.75</Price>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Category>Hardware</Category>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <Name>Hammer</Name>
        <Price>16.99</Price>
    </Product>
</ArrayOfProduct>
</script>
```

**JS**

```
$.mockjax({
  url: '/testXML/',
  responseTime: 0,
  contentType: 'text/xml',
  responseText: $('#xmlData').text()
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/testXML/",
        type: "GET"
    }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert($(data).find('Product:eq(0) > Category').text());
    }).fail(function (jqXhr, textStatus) {
        alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried to set the dataType to xml (which is how I see it in the browser) and also to remove it but it doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Is your XML well formed? Is there only 1 parent node? `<parent><child></child><child><subchild></subchild></child></parent>` would be valid, but `<parent><child></child></parent><parent><child></child></parent>` would not. All your xml needs to be wrapped by a single parent node.

Comment: You should add the xml response to your question.